# ClearDb + Azure: Vanilla forum installation really slow

Tags: php, mysql, azure, cleardb, vanilla-forums

Migrated a Vanilla forum (php) to an Azure website with a cleardb mysql database.

It's working but performance is horrible in terms of page loading compared to my previous installation. I'm guessing it's the db connection that's slow but maybe it could be caching not working?

Any pointers on what I can do to investigate/solve the problem? Any suggestion on how I can prove it's an issue with cleardb?

Anyone used cleardb and Azure and had performance issues?

/Niels

Comment: As stated, the question is too broad. "too slow" or "performance is horrible" doesn't give any details. It could be related to the service tier for ClearDB. It could be the service tier for Websites. It could be other things. What have you diagnosed so far? Please edit your question with more concrete details. As it stands, this might fit better on ServerFault if it's just about infrastructure deployment and not programming-related.

Comment: I know you asked this a long time ago,  but it was the same time we tried using ClearDB,  we came to the conclusion that ClearDB were simply awful,  the performance was dreadful.  So we ended up with  vm's hosting mysql, which is not really so cloud.  I now have a project again indicated as a php Azure project,  but for obvious (ClearDB) reasons they want to use Azure SQL,  which is not really a good option for PHP frameworks.  Did you manage to find a good solution with ClearDB?  thanks.

Comment: No I never did. I ended up moving away from Vanilla Forum.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what cleardb plan you have. https://www.cleardb.com/store/azure

The free one (Mercury) has very slow performance, especially write. Try at least upgrading to Venus, it should have moderate performance.

Make sure you implement Persistent Connections. Otherwise, every call to the database will be treated as a new connection.
http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

For example, here is plugin for wordpress that implements it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/persistent-database-connection-updater/

What Azure Websites plan do you use? Bear in mind, Shared or 1 virtual Core CPU Basic/Standard might be quite slow.

Comment: I'm on the Venus plan and on a Standard Medium Azure hosting plan (other sites work fine).

Answer (score 0):

Please see this as well. In short - add the following line to a file called ".user.ini" located at the web root:
output_buffering = Off;

Source:
https://thorstenhoffmann.com/2015/06/08/speeding-up-wordpress-on-azure-web-apps-with-cleardb-disable-output-buffering-in-php/